# Efficient way to find frequencies of each unique value in the std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, unique

Given a vector `std::vector<double> v`, we can find unique elements efficiently by:

```
std::vector<double> uv(v.begin(), v.end());
std::sort(uv.begin(), uv.end());
std::erase(std::unique(uv.begin, uv.end()), uv.end());
```

What would the be the nicest way (without loops, with STL or lambdas) to create a vector:

```
std::vector<double> freq_uv(uv.size());
```

which would contain frequencies of each distinct element appearing in `v` (order the same as sorted unique values)?

Note: type can be anything, not just `double`

Comment: I need the frequencies from original vector `v` (for each unique value stored in `uv`)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: She means the frequency of the element in the original range...

Comment: I see. The nicest way would require a loop, or an algorithm function which does not exist in the standard library, and which would be implemented with a loop.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, could you please share what kind of snippet you have in your mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you sort, before you erase:

```
std::vector<int> freq_uv;
freq_uv.push_back(0);
auto prev = uv[0];        // you should ensure !uv.empty() if previous code did not already ensure it.
for (auto const & x : uv)
{
    if (prev != x)
    {
        freq_uv.push_back(0);
        prev = x;
    }
    ++freq_uv.back();
}
```

Note that, while I generally like to count occurences with a map, as Yakk is doing, in this case I think it is doing a lot of unnecessary work as we already know the vector is sorted.

Another possibility is to use a `std::map` (not unordered), *instead* of sorting. This will get your frequencies first. Then, since the map is ordered, you can just create the sorted, unique vector, and the frequency vector directly from the map.

```
// uv not yet created
std::map<T, int> freq_map;
for (auto const & x : v)
    ++freq_map[x];
std::vector<T> uv;
std::vector<int> freq_uv;
for (auto const & p : freq_map)
{
    uv.push_back(p.first);
    freq_uv.push_back(p.second);
}
```

Comment: Although an elegant solution, there is a stipulation that disallows loops.

Comment: @dreamlax: I told OP that a loop is required. OP asked for my solution anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, very nice solution. I think in terms of complexity it's the most efficient you can go, although with the loops

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, yes, your note is completely correct. I have to find unique elements anyway, so using this is a very good idea

Comment: I would advise against the `std::map` solution.  The O(n lg n) cache-unfriendly operations may seem more efficient, but a O(n lg n) cache-friendly sort with O(n) `unordered_map` cache-unfriendly lookups both matches it in O-notation, and I would get would blow it away in performance.  `std::map` is pretty much only fastest when you need the elements in order *on the fly* as you add/remove elements.  In a second optimization, make `prev` a pointer that starts out as `nullptr`, and change your condition to `if (!pref || *prev!=x)` (etc) to make your first solution more robust and simpler .

Answer (score 4):

First, note that `==` and to a lesser extent `<` on `double` is often a poor idea: often you'll have values that logically "should" be equal if the `double` was infinite precision, but are slightly different.

However, collecting the frequencies is easy:

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator>
std::unordered_map< T, std::size_t > frequencies( std::vector<T, Allocator> const& src ) {
  std::unordered_map< T, std::size_t > retval;
  for (auto&& x:src)
    ++retval[x];
  return retval;
}
```

assuming `std::hash<T>` is defined (which it is for `double`).  If not, there is more boilerplate, so I'll skip it.  Note that this does not care if the `vector` is sorted.

If you want it in the form of `std::vector<std::size_t>` in sync with your sorted `vector`, you can just do this:

```
template<typename T, typename Hash, typename Equality, typename Allocator>
std::vector<std::size_t> collate_frequencies(
  std::vector<T, Allocator> const& order,
  std::unordered_map<T, std::size_t, Hash, Equality> const& frequencies
) {
  std::vector<std::size_t> retval;
  retval.reserve(order.size());
  for( auto&& x : order )
    retval.push_back( frequencies[x] );
  return retval;
}
```

I took the liberty of making these functions overly generic, so they support more than just `double`s.

Answer (score 1):

using `equal_range`:

```
std::vector<int> results;
for(auto i = begin(v); i != end(v);)
{
    auto r = std::equal_range(i, end(v), *i);
    results.emplace_back( std::distance(r.first, r.second) );
    i = r.second;
}
```

---

SSCCE:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> v{1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 3.0};
    std::sort(begin(v), end(v));

    std::vector<int> results;
    for(auto i = begin(v); i != end(v);)
    {
        auto r = std::equal_range(i, end(v), *i);
        results.emplace_back( std::distance(r.first, r.second) );
        i = r.second;
    }

    for(auto const& e : results) std::cout << e << "; ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An O(n) solution when the range of values is limited, for example chars. Using less than the CPU level 1 cache for the counter leaves room for other values.

(untested code)

```
constexp int ProblemSize = 256;
using CountArray = std::array<int, ProblemSize>;

CountArray CountUnique(const std::vector<char>& vec) {
  CountArray count;
  for(const auto ch : vec)
    count[ch]++;

  return count;
}
```